# undefined value in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a parse function that is used to fetch data from backend.

```
parse : function(resp){

        resp.id = resp.ID;
        return resp;            
    },
```

and I want to use resp.id as a path to the url that is going to use in my ajax post to  then fetching data from that url. resp.id is a number. but when I write the following, `resp.ID` is undefined in antoher function. I also used `this.respId` but the value of it is undefined. my problem is that this resp.id is not defined in ajaxpost function

```
url: "/Api/v1",
    callAjaxPost : function{
        url : this.url + "/resp.Id/List",
    }
```

Comment: res is undefined in parse function. Maybe: res.id = resp.ID; ?

Comment: Did you make a typo in asking question here or in your main code as well??   `resp.id = resp.ID;
        return res;` shouldn't it be `res.id = resp.ID`??

Comment: What is res? We need more code to answer this!

Comment: After fix, the link uses resp.Id, which is not defined, while resp.id and resp.ID should be.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. ID, id, Id and iD will all different variables.

Comment: You keep posting questions about what appears to be the same bit of code, yet you keep posting them with minimal information, and you fail to respond to comments. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

How is the parse function being called. What does the `resp` that gets passed to it come from?

Why do you need to do `resp.id = resp.ID`?  Also, why are you returning `res` which doesn't appear to exist?

A little more information and clarification would make answering this question easier.

Comment: You should get your questions clarified by commenting on the question.

Comment: Vineeth, I would, but I need 50 reputation to comment and I only have 26.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you return res, not resp in the parse function, which you don't show how it is used.

Also, in your callAjaxPost function, you write resp.ID in the string.
The url will be something like h..p://localhost/resp.ID/List while I would suspect that you wanted the actual ID in the link.
Try:

```
url : this.url + "/" + resp.ID + "/List";
```

Comment: my problem is that this resp.id is not defined in ajaxpost function

Comment: How do you call on the parse function?

Comment: I think the problem is the ajax function which is called from another view and when a user clicks it triggers this ajax post. parse function is working correct since when I use console.log() within the parse function it shows the correct value but from the ajax it returns undefined

Comment: That is possible, you could show some code on how you use the functions you have shown and how they are supposed to work together.

Answer (score 0):

variable `res` in return statement of parse function is undefined, there is nothing about it in the function.

Another mistake is using resp.ID in callAjaxPost. It figures out as a sting. Maybe you want to code:

```
url : this.url + "/" + resp.ID + "/List",
```